# Checkbox does not work after using jQuery ImageTick

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I found nice plugin to replace checkbox with an image [here](http://boedesign.com/blog/2008/06/08/imagetick-for-jquery/).  I have use it and it works, for simple scenario like [this example](http://boedesign.com/demos/imagetick/).

Now, I have this scenario :

I have one checkbox as a **group**, some checkboxes as **sub-groups** and some checkboxes as **options** of sub-group.

When I checked the group, all sub-groups and options will be checked too.
When I checked the sub-group, all options of this sub-group will be checked too.

I have made it using jquery and it works without imagetick. See http://jsfiddle.net/arif_rh/GBLy3/8/,

but when I use imagetick, it does not work. See http://jsfiddle.net/arif_rh/P7Fje/3/

What did I miss??

Answer (score 0):

If you check the rendered html an Image tag is placed with the checkbox dispaly:none. So what you need to do is toggle the image and not check the checkbox here

```
<td>
    <img src="http://i49.tinypic.com/1198b3s.png" alt="no_tick" class="ticks_551845" id="tick_img_9">
    <input type="checkbox" id="9" class="g_1 s_21" name="opsi" value="1" style="display: block; ">
</td>
```

The code that has to be written to get the expected output is .. Also this can be collapsed into a single event instead of separate click events for each checkbox..

```
    $('#s_11 , #s_21 , #s_31').click(function ()
{
    if( $(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).parent().parent().find('td:gt(0) img').attr('src','http://i47.tinypic.com/4t3nh3.png');
    }
    else{
         $(this).parent().parent().find('td:gt(0) img').attr('src','http://i49.tinypic.com/1198b3s.png')
    }
   // $('.s_11').attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/P7Fje/4/)

Comment: Hi @ssushanth, thanks for your quick response. I see that works when I checked a sub group, then all the options being checked too.  But it still doesn't work when I checked the group. Even when I checked option, one by one, it does nothing.